# Node temporary npm install done programmatically

Tags: node.js, module, npm

I would like to programmatically `npm install` a package using a Node app, after the node app has started. Ideally, this package would not file into my `node_modules` folder, but rather would trash itself after runtime.

[`npm` supports programmatic installs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm), however it seems to actually save the modules into `node_modules`. Additionally, making the entirety of `npm` (a big module) a requirement for this kind of sucks. However, when I looked at the source code, the `npm install` part uses a ton of modules and isn't something I can easily reproduce.

Is there any other module that anyone knows about that meets this requirement?

Comment: Emm... What about installing to node_modules, then just move it to another dir?

Comment: That's the right train of thought. I basically ended up doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Found with NPM you can install to a path, and there's this nifty `temp` module that helps do that cross platform:

```
var temp = require('temp')
  , npm = require('npm')
  ;

function use(module, cb) {
  npm.load({}, function(){
    npm.commands.install(temp.dir, [module], function(err, data){
      var dir = data[0][1];
      var mod = require(__dirname + '/' + dir);
      cb(mod);
    });  
  })
}

use('lodash', function(_){
  // ... do things.
});
```

If you want to, `temp` has a `clean` function that can clean up the temp dir later.

Comment: As for 2022 this solution doesn't work anymore, npm >8.0.0 deprecated programmatic API, therefore `var npm = require("npm");` inside the project is no longer possible.